# onClick takeScreenShot causes suspend

Tags: java, android, debugging

UPDATE BELOW

App continues to suspend. I'm attempting to get a screenshot with a button click. It suspends when I click the button. This is what I get in the debug perspective:

```
MainActivity$1.onClick(View) line: 108  
Button(View).performClick() line: 4438  
View$PerformClick.run() line: 18422 
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 733   
ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 95 
Looper.loop() line: 136 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5017    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not   available [native method]    
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 515  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 779  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 595 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

I use an onClick to take a screen shot as shown here:

```
            public void onClick(View view) {




            Activity MainActivity = null;
  //Line 108  View view1 = MainActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
             view1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
             view1.buildDrawingCache();
             Bitmap b1 = view1.getDrawingCache();
             Rect frame = new Rect();
             MainActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
             int statusBarHeight = frame.top;
             int width = MainActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
             int height = MainActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

             Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height  - statusBarHeight);
             view1.destroyDrawingCache();

             FileOutputStream fos = null;
             try
             {
                 fos = new FileOutputStream(strFileName);
                 if (null != fos)
                 {
                     b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
                     fos.flush();
                     fos.close();
                 }
             }
             catch (FileNotFoundException e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             catch (IOException e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }



        }
```

-----------------------------------UPDATE------------------------------------------

I took the method out of the onClick(). I created a second activity called ScreenShot.java as you can see here:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;

public class ScreenShot extends MainActivity {


private static Bitmap takeScreenShot(Activity MainActivity)
{
    View view = MainActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();
    Rect frame = new Rect();
    MainActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
    int statusBarHeight = frame.top;
    int width = MainActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int height = MainActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height  - statusBarHeight);
    view.destroyDrawingCache();
    return b;
}
private static void savePic(Bitmap b, String strFileName)
{
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try
    {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(strFileName);
        if (null != fos)
        {
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I then placed an intent to start ScreenShot.class within the onClick() of the MainActivity:

```
Intent myIntentg = new Intent(view.getContext(), ScreenShot.class);
             startActivityForResult(myIntentg, 0);
```

I also added the new ScreenShot.java to the manifest.

Now the only thing that happens is my current activity kind of flashes and starts over, but no screenshot is taken or anything else happens.

Comment: Does control ever return or do you end up w/ an ANR?  I'd suggest threading out the Button click vs having it run on the main thread.

Comment: @d3n13d1 I get an ANR

Comment: Yeah then surround it instead with a Thread and you should be OK that way it will not lock up the UI.  If there's still issue then you'll know more.

Comment: is MainActivity the same Activity where this code lives? If not, it might be that trying to get windows and decor view from a suspended activity won't come back at all.

Comment: @Martin MainActivity is the Activity where it's all happening.

Comment: onClick executes in the main thread.  Get reference to whatever UI objects you need then thread the actual saving of the info out.

Comment: @d3n13d1 I'm not sure I understand. I created another activity titled ScreenShot.java and then I placed an Intent in the onClick() to start the ScreenShot.class. Inside ScreenShot.class I have the takeScreenShot method.When I click all I get is a blank activity starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reason to launch a different intent.  In your onclick method just thread out the call to the methods that actually do the work.

```
  onClick(View view) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Call your methods
            }
        }).start();
 }
```